# How to change the subscript/index value in an associative array?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to change the subscript/index value of an existing element in an associative array?

```
 declare
  type a_arr is table of varchar2(20) index by pls_integer;
  tb1 a_arr;
 begin
  tb1(1) := 'aaaa';
  tb1(2) := 'bbbb';
  tb1(3) := 'cccc';
 end;
 /
```

In the above associative array `tb1`, is it possible to change the subscript value from 1 to 10 (ie from `tb1(1)` to `tb1(10)`) without deleting or creating a new element in the table?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible without deleting because associative arrays can't be popped like we could do in a Python dictionary. What are you trying to accomplish with it anyway?

Comment: @KaushikNayak : Actually I just wanted to know if we can change the subscript value of an associate array. Had a requirement where we needed to add emp_id as index value which points to the salary. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what are you trying to do. Here's basic general example. The output is 'aaaa' 10 times. You can add some logic in between. For example, if i = 3 then tbl_val:= 'bbbb' or smth lk this. You can also parameterise the start and/or end loop boundaries if you create a procedure for example.

```
DECLARE
  type a_arr is table of varchar2(20) index by pls_integer;
  tb1 a_arr;
  tbl_val VARCHAR2(20):= 'aaaa';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    tb1(i):= tbl_val;
    dbms_output.put_line(tb1(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```